# Is it possible to log a default value for a custom header in nginx log

Tags: nginx

I am extracting custom header values and logging them in the access log file using a custom log format:

```
log_format custom  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
    '$http_my_custom_header'
```

When logging requests that do not contain the header, `ngx_http_log_module` inserts a `-` into the logs. Is it possible to define a default value for missing headers? I need the header to always have a numeric value for later indexing in elasticsearch.

I have a workaround using map which sets the header value to `0` when absent:

```
map $http_my_custom_header $custom_header {
    default $http_my_custom_header;
    '' 0;
}
log_format custom  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
    '$custom_header'
```

I'm hoping for a more elegant solution as I will be adding more headers in the future.